# Accessing iCloud Drive files via AppleScript

Tags: icloud, applescript, hfs

I am trying to get AppleScript to open a file located at iCloud Drive:Documents:Manuals:BBEdit_13.0.1_User_Manual.pdf.

```
tell application "Finder"
    open file "/Users/cb/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Manuals/Computer/BBEdit_13.0.1_User_Manual.pdf.icloud"
end tell
```

I obtained the filepath by right clocking the target file + option key & selecting copy... as filename.

Running the script results in error

```
Finder got an error: Can’t get file \"/Users/cb/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Manuals/Computer/BBEdit_13.0.1_User_Manual.pdf\"." number -1728 from file "/Users/cb/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Manuals/Computer/BBEdit_13.0.1_User_Manual.pdf"
```

What am I doing wrong? Does anyone know what AppleScript error -1728 means?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_codes.html.

Comment: The target file in your command has an '.icloud' extension, after the '.pdf' extension. I don't really use icloud drive so maybe that's how it should be but you could try removing it. Oh… and what @Alper said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AppleScript error 1728](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_codes.html) means:

> The referenced object doesn’t exist. This is a run-time resolution
> error, such as when attempting to reference a third object when only
> two objects exist.

Assuming the specified file in your code really exists and the correct full path is as specified, the underlying problem leading to this error in your code should be that you are not telling the interpreter that your [file path format](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReferenceFilesandFolders.html) is POSIX:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open POSIX file "/Users/cb/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Manuals/Computer/BBEdit_13.0.1_User_Manual.pdf.icloud"
end tell
```

The alternative would be to use HFS for the file path:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open "Macintosh HD:Users:cb:Library:Mobile Documents:com~apple~CloudDocs:Documents:Manuals:Computer:BBEdit_13.0.1_User_Manual.pdf.icloud"
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you @Alper. The .icloud suffix was added automatically to the filepath when right clicking the target file + option key & selecting copy... as filename. Removing it didn't help. However both the "open POSIX file.." and using HFS for the file path work.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for confirming the icloud extension. I did not know that. I understand that's the case for the files whose full copies only reside in iCloud. In my case, however, once the script is executed at least once, the full copy of the file gets downloaded to the local drive. Then, the path with the icloud extension causes an error the next time the script is executed. However, that may or may not be the case if "Optimize Mac Storage" is selected in ->System Settings->Apple ID->iCloud which is not the case for me.